# Can't install jQuerybundle for eclipse aptana studio 3 plugin installed

Tags: jquery, eclipse, aptana, bundle

I have installed aptana studio 3 plugin to eclipse.
But i can't install jQuerybundle.

When i select Command->Bundel Developemnt->Install Bundel->jQuery, message like below is shown:

```
****** ~/Aptana Rubles
$ git clone git://github.com/aptana/javascript-jquery.ruble.git
Cloning into javascript-jquery.ruble...
github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=No such file or directory
fatal: unable to connect a socket (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 8):

Got it working by manually copying the files.So may be you could try this

1) Download the zip from https://github.com/aptana/javascript-jquery.ruble/downloads

2) Go to the folder C:\Documents and Settings\"your_username"\Aptana Rubles and unzip the contents to this folder.(Windows XP 32 bit).

3) Restart eclipse

4) Create any web project.Right click.Go to Preference -> Project Build Path and select the checkbox for either jQuery 1.4.2 or jQuery 1.6.2 as the case may be.

Comment: Thanks a lot - works like a charm. 
For me with Windows 7 64 Bit the Path is C:\Users\USERNAME\Aptana Rubles

Comment: The downloads folder wasn't working for me. I went to: https://github.com/aptana/javascript-jquery.ruble and clicked the Download ZIP button on the right

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me from behind a proxy.

Use these three commands to clone jQuery Ruble in Aptana Studio from behind proxy:

```
$ git config --global http.proxy http://typeYourProxyHere:8080

$ git config --global https.proxy http://typeYourProxyHere:8080

$ git clone https://github.com/aptana/javascript-jquery.ruble.git
```

From: http://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/3340-git-problems-behind-firewall-cant-install-bundles