# Internal error: github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=No error fatal: unable to connect a socket (No error)

Tags: eclipse, github, aptana

I'm pretty much a start up (noob) in this whole coding thing. But I have my eclipse running with the aptana studio plugin. I open a new web project, and click on the "HTML5 Boilerplate" Option, and upon creating the project, get this error message:
Internal error:

github.com[0: 192.30.252.130]: errno=No error
fatal: unable to connect a socket (No error)

when I click on the eclipse "Problem Occured" prompt on "Details"
I am not sure of how to fix this problem. I already installed the git plugins on eclipse and everything, if that was a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the GitHub url for the HTML5 boilerplate repo.

But if you are behind a firewall, chances are that url is an ssh one, and ssh is blocked.
If you have not control over said url, and cannot [change it to an https one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16301991/6309), you still can attempts a manual download and installation, [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9312226/6309).

Answer (score 2):

This solved my issue....
Bypass git using git:// addresses, force them to use https://

> git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://

To revert the settings back to git port, use below command

> git config --global --unset url."https://".insteadOf

[git](/questions/tagged/git) [github](/questions/tagged/github)